# Density of $X + Y$ when $X$ is discrete and $Y$ has a density

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

> Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables where $X$ is discrete and $Y$ has a density $f$. Prove: $X + Y$ has a density.

I can not really deal with the "vague" specifications, e.g. what is the sample space? What is the measure function? What is the $\sigma$-algebra? I know, the reason is that the mathematic model does not matter in the end but for me, I have issues in understanding the assumptions.

Actually, I should real it like follows, shouldn't I?

Lez $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P), (\Omega', \mathcal A', P')$ be probability spaces and $X,Y: \Omega \to \Omega'$ be random variables with distributions

$$P^X: \mathcal A'\to[0,1], \quad A' \mapsto P(X^{-1}(A')), \qquad P^Y: \mathcal A'\to[0,1], \quad A'\mapsto P(Y^{-1}(A'))$$

where

- $X$ is discrete, which means $X(\Omega)$ is finite,
- $Y$ has density $f$, which means $P^Y(A') = \displaystyle\int_{A'} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ (we only defined random variables with a density for distributions on $\mathbb R$ - so $(\Omega', \mathcal A') = (\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$?)

So I have to prove that there is a function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $\displaystyle P^{X+Y}(A') = \int_{A'} g(x) \, \mathrm dx$? Probably I should construct $g$, shouldn't I? But how?

I already got to $P^{X+Y}(A') = P((X+Y)^{-1}(A'))$ but at this point I'm stuck because $(X+Y)^{-1}(A') \neq X^{-1}(A') + Y^{-1}(A')$?

I'm really just very confused by all the terms. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take $\Omega'=\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal A'=\mathcal B$ for this to make sense.

If $x_1,x_2,..$ are the values of $X$ then $P(X+Y\leq z)=\sum_n P(Y \leq z-x_n )P(X=x_n)$. This can be writen as $\sum_n p_n\int_{-\infty} ^{z-x_n} f(t)dt $ where $p_n=P(X=x_n)$. By a change of variable this becomes $\sum_n p_n\int_{-\infty} ^{z} f(t-x_n)dt $. Thus $P(X+Y \leq z)=\int_{-\infty} ^{z} g(t)dt$ where $g(t)=\sum_n p_nf(t-x_n)$. Verify that $g$ is a non-negative measurable function whose integral equals $1$. This proves that $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous with density $g$.

I have repeatedly used the fact when the integrand is non-negative an infinite sum and an integral can be interchanged.